# When I create a sentinel of redis-plus-plus, an exception is raised

Tags: exception, redis, c++17, visual-studio-2022, redis-sentinel

Please forgive me for not speaking English well.

I am trying to use the redis sentinel function.
When I create a sentinel of redis-plus-plus, an exception is raised.

Exception occurs when Sentinel is created as shown in the code below.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5002.png)

Exceptions are as follows.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf1uI.png)

I've also asked git about the issue.
https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues/342

Please help me.

Environment:

- OS: windows7
- Compiler: visual studio 2022 / unicode
- hiredis version: master (date: 2022-2-2 2:10, commit:f8de9a4)
- redis-plus-plus version: master (date: 2022-2-8 23:30, commit:244e8cb)
- c++ version : 17

Comment: Since redis-plus-plus might throw exception, please try-catch the exception, and show us the error message of the exception.

Comment: @for_stack. I wrote a related article on github. thank you.